# How to use PHP spreadsheet in drupal 7 for reading excel file and storing in database

Tags: php, drupal-7, phpexcel, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I'm new in Drupal 7, I want to use PHP Spreadsheet in my project, but how much i know that PHP spreadheet module is available in Drupal 8, and for Drupal 7 we need to use it's library, so I followed this steps for PHP spreadsheet

1. Download the PhpSpreadsheet library and extract it inside your site's libraries folder:

- sites/all/libraries/PhpSpreadsheet

2. Run "composer install" in folder libraries/PhpSpreadsheet to install all the dependencies

so what i need to do next and how to start using it in our custom module this things I'm not getting and which steps I need to follow, Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in documentation https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , just read it and apply.